# C# server logging to text file from console

Tags: c#, console, streamwriter

I currently have a client which is communicating with a server on localhost. When the client communicates with the server, the server keeps track of what is happening, eg.

```
string response = "Location updated for " + uname + ": " + uloc;
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

I am trying to keep a log of whatever the server console is listing by writing it out to the text file declared like so in the "public class".

```
public static System.IO.StreamWriter serverlog = new System.IO.StreamWriter("serverlog.txt", true);
```

I tried adding a writeline to the txt file as shown below.

```
 string response = "Location updated for: " + commands[0];
 Console.WriteLine(response);
 serverlog.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + "] [Server]: " + response);
 serverlog.close();
```

However, when I try to write to serverlog.txt again after `serverlog.close();` is executed, it completely screws up the program, and no command from client to server can be executed again unless the program is re-run from Visual Studio. How do I re open the streamwriter again so I can append to the text file while the server is still running?

Let me know if more of my code is needed.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
static void WriteToLog(string logtext)
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText("nserverlog.txt", string.Format("{0}{1}", logtext, Environment.NewLine));
    }


WriteToLog("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + "] [Server]: " + response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you close the `serverlog` object, you have to re-open it every time you want to use it.  Rather than go through that whole mess, just use the `File` class:

`System.IO.File.AppendAllText(filepath, "text to write");`

That will handle all the streamwriting etc. internally.  Nothing to instantiate, nothing to close.

I suggest you create some sort of logging class that has a `writeToLog(String)` method.  Inside that method, you could write to the console and to the log file and to anywhere else you want, rather than explicitly doing both every time.